# Laravel - Error rendering views during deployment using blade syntax

Tags: apache, laravel, linode, laravel-3

I'm getting this error:

```
Message:
View [partials.headerHome] doesn't exist.

Location:
/home/user/public/site.com/laravel/view.php on line 170
```

Which is being caused by this blade templating include

```
@include('partials.headerHome')
```

Which translates to this when it gets run through the templating engine and ends up in /storage

```
<?php echo view('partials.headerHome')->with(get_defined_vars())->render(); ?>
```

I'm using Linode, and I believe that I have everything set up correctly, have a couple of other sites running fine. My document root is hitting /public just as it was in development. What could be the issue here?

```
Currently sorting through the error log..
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the references to the partial and their filenames to all lower case, and your problems will go away. You probably didn't have any issues in development because your local machine is using a case-insensitive filesystem. Mac OSX, for example, is case-insensitive by default.

Comment: Good catch, that was the exact problem.